# Error when using sql query containing IFNULL and serial number column in Phoenix

Tags: mysql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
Select 
    @sl:=@sl+1 as slNum,
    IFNULL(startTime,'-'),
from 
    race,
    (Select @s1:=0) x ;
```

I get the desired result when i run the above query in mysql, but I want to execute the same query on Phoenix for the table stored in Hbase.
I get the following error for @sl:

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "@" at line 'x', column 'y'.
Caused by: NoViableAltException(15@[])
```

And when I comment out the serial number, i get this:

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 603 (42P00): Syntax error. Unexpected input. Expecting "LPAREN", got "IFNULL" at line x2, column y2.
Caused by: UnwantedTokenException(found=IFNULL, expected 91)
```

Does Phoenix not support them or is there some other way of doing this?
Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether or not Phoenix supports dynamic SQL, but there is a way to generate row number without dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(r1.startTime, '-') AS startTime
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM race r2 WHERE r2.startTime <= r1.startTime) slNum
FROM race r1;
```

I assume that the start time provides the ordering.  Your current logic is not well defined using row number without an ordering.  You may replace `startTime` with another column in the `WHERE` clause of my subquery.

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there an easy way of getting only the date(dd/mm/yyyy) from a time column (time column format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS)

Comment: @Nish Yes, just use `DATE('2018-02-12 00:00:00')`.  This should return just the date portion.

Comment: I had tried that and but it said 'Function undefined' for phoenix. It did work for mysql.

Comment: `DATE` is the easy way, the other methods are harder.  You might want to open a new question for this.